# Where clause with information that might not exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a temp table with phones that needs to be checked against a log table.

**Temp table**

- Phone varchar(20)

**Log Table**

- Phone varchar(20)
- [Status]  varchar(20)
- ChangeDate DateTime

**Log Table Data**

- Every phone in the log table will always have a status of "Added"
- But not every phone will also have the status of "Removed"

**Example:**

- **Phone           Status       ChangeDate**
- 3054444444  Added     10-12-2012
- 4445556666  Added     10-12-2012
- 3054444444  Removed   11-12-2012

**Where clause has 2 sections, and they both have to be true**

**1. The Temp.Phone can join when:**

- @Date is bigger or equal to log.ChangeDate
- log.Status = 'Added'

**Here is the tricky part....that I can't figure out**

**2. The Join also needs to make sure that:**

- @Date is smaller than log.ChangeDate
- when log.Status = 'removed'
- log.Status = 'removed' might not exist, so I need to check if it exists then its true, and if does not exist, then ignore or generate a true somehow

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT *
FROM #temp t
JOIN log l
ON t.Phone = l.Phone
WHERE  (l.ChangeDate < = @Date AND  l.Status = 'Added')    
  AND 
       (l.ChangeDate > @Date AND l.Status = 'Removed') --may not exist, but ALSO has to be true
```

Comment: If you change your second "and" to "or", Bob might be your uncle.

Comment: I can't....they both have to be true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM #temp t
JOIN log l
  ON t.Phone = l.Phone
WHERE (l.ChangeDate < = @Date AND  l.Status = 'Added')    
  AND (
   (l.ChangeDate > @Date AND l.Status = 'Removed')
  or not exists(
       select 'removed'
       from log l2
       where l2.phone = t.phone
       and l2.ChangeDate > @Date AND l2.Status = 'Removed'
    )
  )
```

Comment: I think the `>` needs to be changed to `<=` in the sub query since it is a `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: @David: Mmm no, not exists a next date where you removed the phone, I suppose.

Comment: This still appears to be based on the concept that field l.ChangeDate is both less than and greater than the @Date parameter.  It looks fishy to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can either join a 2nd time to the log table or use the `NOT EXISTS` clause, but make sure you check the date inequality...

```
SELECT *
FROM #temp t
    INNER JOIN log l
    ON t.Phone = l.Phone
    AND l.Status = 'Added'
    AND l.ChangeDate <= @Date
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Log
    -- This makes sure that the phone wasn't removed in between the date it was
    -- added and the date you are querying.
    WHERE Log.ChangeDate > l.ChangeDate
        AND Log.ChangeDate <= @Date
        AND Log.Phone = t.Phone
        AND Log.Status = 'Removed'
  )
```